# Why does my ArrayList in Android Studio only show the last position, overwriting the others?

Tags: java, android, arrays, gridview, arraylist

1. package com.example.saulo.apptest;

```
import android.nfc.Tag; 
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class Movie {
    private String disciplina;
    private int rating ;
    private String professor ;

    List<String> disciplinas;
    List<String> professores;



    public  Movie newInstance() {
        disciplinas = new ArrayList<>();
        professores = new ArrayList<>();


        Movie movie = new Movie ();

        disciplinas.add(0, "Comportamento organizacinal");
        disciplinas.add(1, "graducao");
        professores.add(0, "Ana Maria");
        professores.add(1, "Luciana");

        //Random random = new Random ();
        // ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String d : disciplinas){
        movie.setDisciplina(d);
        }
         for(String p : professores) {
        movie.setProfessor(p);

         }
        // list.add(movie);
        //  movie.setDisciplina (disciplinas [random.nextInt (disciplinas.length)]);
        //   movie.setRating (random.nextInt (5) + 1);
        //   movie.setYear (1980 + random.nextInt(37) );

        return movie;
    }

    public String getDisciplina() {
        return disciplina;
    }

    public void setDisciplina(String disciplina) {
        this.disciplina = disciplina;
    }

    public String getProfessor() {
        return professor;
    }

    public void setProfessor(String professor) {
        this.professor = professor;
    } }
```

2. package com.example.saulo.apptest;

```
import android.content.Context; import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import
android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class MovieAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

    private int resource ;

    public MovieAdapter (Context context , int resource , List<Movie> objects ) {
        super(context, resource, objects );
        this.resource = resource ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
        View row = convertView ;

        if (row == null ) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(this.resource, parent, false );
        }

        Movie movie = getItem ( position );

        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.disciplina);
        name.setText(movie.getDisciplina());

        TextView professor = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.professor);
        professor.setText(" Professor : " + movie.getProfessor());

        // TextView rating = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        // rating.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getRating()));

        return row;
    } }
```

3. package com.example.saulo.apptest;

```
import android.nfc.Tag; import
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log; import android.view.View; import
android.widget.AdapterView; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView; import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_grid_view);


        initAdvancedGridView();
        initGridView();

    }

    private ArrayList<String> createItemsList() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            list.add("Item" + i);
        }

        return list ;
    }



    private ArrayList <Movie> createMoviesList() {
        ArrayList <Movie> list = new ArrayList <Movie>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
            Movie movie = new Movie();

            list.add(movie.newInstance());
        }

        return list ;
    }

    private void initGridView () {
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        if (gridView == null) {
            return;
        }


        ArrayList<String > list = createItemsList();

        ArrayAdapter<String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initAdvancedGridView(){
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.advanced_grid_view);

        if (gridView == null) {
            return ;
        }

        ArrayList<Movie> list = createMoviesList();

        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter (this, R.layout.grid_view_item, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Movie movie = (Movie) parent.getAdapter().getItem( position );

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, movie.getDisciplina() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Although an explanation of what the code does and what you want to achieve would have been nice I think that it has to do with this part in your Movie class:

```
for(String d : disciplinas){
    movie.setDisciplina(d);
}

for(String p : professores) {
    movie.setProfessor(p);
}
```

I'm not sure what the methods do, but you should check if these methods do something like this:

```
public void setDisciplina(String disciplina) {
    disciplinaList.add(disciplina);
}
```

Comment: i'm setting the datas into de setters in order to show it in a gridview, but when i run tha app it only show the last position